# помогите с расположением карточек в html

Tags: html, css

на практике выдали задание, сделать сайт по шаблону, всё шло хорошо пока не дошёл до карточек. они располагаются по вертикали, а мне надо чтоб по горизонтали. как это делать, ломаю голову

```css
* {
  box-sizibg: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
}

header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E73D66;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.logo-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-elem {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav-elem a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

p.change-text:hover {
  color: #5265f6;
}

.nav-elem a:hover {
  color: #FFB0C3;
}

.promo_title {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 19em;
  position: relative;
}

.promo_title1 {
  color: #e73d66;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.promo_title2 {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 19em;
  position: relative;
}

.promo_title3 {
  color: #e73d66;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.promo_image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1420px;
  height: 579px;
  left: 245px;
  top: 392px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

.about_text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 780px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 570px;
  top: 890px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
}

.mission {
  position: absolute;
  width: 780px;
  height: 105px;
  left: 570px;
  top: 995px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
}

.button1_text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 45px 21px 50px;
  gap: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 715px;
  top: 1115px;
  background: #E73D66;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 137px;
  height: 19px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.button2_text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 50px 21px;
  gap: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 965px;
  top: 1115px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(231, 61, 102, 0.4);
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #E73D66;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.our_text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1180px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 370px;
  top: 1275px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444444;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  /*background-color: aquamarine;*/
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px overflow: hidden;
}

.card_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
}

.card_image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card_content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card_title {
  color: #E73D66;
  /* Цвет обычной ссылки */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Убираем подчеркивание */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  /* Высота линии */
  background-color: black;
  /* Цвет подчеркивания при исчезании линии*/
  transition: width 0.5s;
  /* Время эффекта */
  color: #E73D66;
}

.card_title:hover:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  height: 2px;
  /* Высота линии */
  background-color: red;
  /* Цвет подчеркивания при появлении линии*/
  transition: width 0.5s;
  /* Время эффекта */
}

.card_description {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #444444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.card_button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(9, 70, 49);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.card_age {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-image"></div>
    <div class="logo-text">ЧЕТЫРЕ<br> ЛАПЫ</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-elem"><a href "">О ПРИЮТЕ</a></div>
    <div class="nav-elem"><a href "">ПИТОМЦЫ</a></div>
    <div class="nav-elem"><a href "">ПОЛЕЗНЫЕ СОВЕТЫ</a></div>
    <div class="nav-elem"><a href "">КОНТАКТЫ</a></div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>

  <div class="promo">
    <h3 class="promo_title">ПРИЮТ ДЛЯ СОБАК <span class="promo_title1">ЧЕТЫРЕ ЛАПЫ</span></h3>
    <h3 class="promo_title2">ВОЗЬМИ ДРУГА <span class="promo_title3">ДОМОЙ</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="promo_image"> <img src="Model21.png"></div>
  <div class="about_company">
    <h3 class="about_text">Помогаем людям и питомцам из приютов<br>встретиться и стать друзьями на всю жизнь</h3>
    <h3 class="mission">Миссия проекта - формирование культуры ответственного отношения к домашним животным.<br> Решение взять кошку или собаку из приюта должно быть осознанным, именно поэтому мы помогаем<br> потенциальным владельцам не только найти питомца, но и подготовиться
      к жизни с новым другом.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <h3 class="button1_text">ВЗЯТЬ ПИТОМЦА</h3>
    <h3 class="button2_text">ПОМОЧЬ ПРИЮТУ</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="our_pets">
    <h3 class="our_text">НАШИ ПИТОМЦЫ</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">


        <div class="card_content">
          <h3 class="card_title">Джек-рассел-терьер</h3>
          <p class="card_description">Майло</p>
          <div class="card_age">2 года | мальчик
            <div class="card_image"> <img src="1.png"></div>

            <div class="flex-container">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">


        <div class="card_content">
          <h3 class="card_title">Лабрадор</h3>
          <p class="card_description">Герта</p>
          <div class="card_age">4 года | девочка
            <div class="card_image"> <img src="2.png"></div>

            <div class="flex-container">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">


        <div class="card_content">
          <h3 class="card_title">лабрадор</h3>
          <p class="card_description">Мартин</p>
          <div class="card_age">1,5 года | мальчик
            <div class="card_image"> <img src="3.png"></div>

            <div class="flex-container">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">


        <div class="card_content">
          <h3 class="card_title">мопс</h3>
          <p class="card_description">чарли</p>
          <div class="card_age">1 год | мальчик
            <div class="card_image"> <img src="4.png"></div>

            <div class="flex-container">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: upd. от безысходности к каждой карточке я дописывал цифру, думал сделать всё по отдельности, но карточки как будто привязаны друг к другу

Comment: upd2. изменил код какой он был раньше

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Все карточки должны быть внутри одного родительского элемента, а у тебя они просто отдельными блоками отдельно друг от друга стоят. Вот пример:

```css
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  /*background-color: aquamarine;*/
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px overflow: hidden;
}

.card_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
}

.card_image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card_content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card_title {
  color: #E73D66;
  /* Цвет обычной ссылки */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Убираем подчеркивание */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card_title:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  /* Высота линии */
  background-color: black;
  /* Цвет подчеркивания при исчезании линии*/
  transition: width 0.5s;
  /* Время эффекта */
  color: #E73D66;
}

.card_title:hover:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  height: 2px;
  /* Высота линии */
  background-color: red;
  /* Цвет подчеркивания при появлении линии*/
  transition: width 0.5s;
  /* Время эффекта */
}

.card_description {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #444444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.card_button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(9, 70, 49);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.card_age {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3 class="card_title">Джек-рассел-терьер</h3>
            <p class="card_description">Майло</p>
            <div class="card_age">2 года | мальчик
                <div class="card_image"> <img src="1.png"></div>

                <div class="flex-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3 class="card_title">Лабрадор</h3>
            <p class="card_description">Герта</p>
            <div class="card_age">4 года | девочка
                <div class="card_image"> <img src="2.png"></div>

                <div class="flex-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3 class="card_title">лабрадор</h3>
            <p class="card_description">Мартин</p>
            <div class="card_age">1,5 года | мальчик
                <div class="card_image"> <img src="3.png"></div>

                <div class="flex-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3 class="card_title">мопс</h3>
            <p class="card_description">чарли</p>
            <div class="card_age">1 год | мальчик
                <div class="card_image"> <img src="4.png"></div>

                <div class="flex-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```